# How to solve "PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. " error in rabbitmq javascript?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, queue, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

After 30 minute I get this error:

```
Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more"
```

I read online that this error is generated because the consumer does not acknowledge the message but I put `noAck:false` so it should acknowledge the message automatically, also in the queue I can see it has been unacked from  rabbitmq manager. So why am I getting this error? How can I solve this? From what is come from?

this is how my queues look like:
[image]

Here is the code for the consumer:

```
 const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertExchange(exchange, exchangeType, { durable: true });
    const assertedQueue = await channel.assertQueue('', {
      exclusive: true,
    }); 
    await channel.bindQueue(assertedQueue.queue, exchange, routingKey);
    await channel.consume(assertedQueue.queue, msg => dbOperation(msg, channel), {
      noAck: false, // send always an answer of confirmation back
    });
```